# Edit function in R and save changes (matlab-style)?

Tags: r

I have some R files containing functions I wrote. I source those files to have the functions available. If foo is my function and I type:

`foo <- edit(foo)`

or

`fix(foo)`

I can change the function and save it just for this session. How can I do the changes permanent, i.e. that they are saved in the source file? So far I am searching for the source file, edit it and then resource it, which can be annoying sometimes. I've seen it in Matlab, that "edit(function)" saves the changes in the source-file of the function.

thanks

Comment: Interesting, it has never crossed my mind that you could develop functions like that. In my experience, a capable IDE is pretty handy for this task. I have multiple .R files open and I modify/save/source them _ad libidum_.

Comment: This is how I do as well most of the time. But I source several function-files at startup of my session - function that I need regularly. Sometimes I am not sure wich of these files contains the function I want to edit, so I search through these files. In these cases it would be great to have a Matlab-like functionality, to edit this function by a call like edit(function) permanently.

Answer (score 3):

I think it depends on what GUI (and hence what OS) you're running R in.  Personally, I'm happy with R.app in OSX,  but there are R-plugins for many common editors such as TextWrangler or Scite.  IIRC these plugins allow you to execute "source" command from the editor so that saving your edits will also update the version of the function in your R-console environment.

Comment: I am using a combination of vim and the vim-r-plugin on Ubuntu Linux and MacOS X. But how can I load the source-file of a function, if I don't know the exact file-name of the source? In the shell (bash) there is the command `which commandname`, that gives me the path to the command, e.g. /usr/bin/bash for `which bash`. Is there somthing simmilar in R, so could type something like: `edit('which foo')` and it opens the source-file?

Answer (score 2):

Will saving the function object work for you? If so, use `save()` on the edited function and `load()` to load it back it. `edit()` and `fix()` are working with the parsed R objects, not the original files so it will be difficult or a pain to deparse them again

```
> foo <- function(x) 1:10
> writeLines("foo.txt", foo)
> writeLines(deparse(foo), "foo.txt")
> readLines("foo.txt")
[1] "function (x) " "1:10" ## not what is wanted
```

As @CarlWitthoft says, you might be better off using one of the many GUI and IDEs available for R. RStudio is very popular and user-friendly and Emacs + ESS is hard to beat.

Comment: Note that (unless `keep.source` is disabled) functions will generally have their source in the `'source'` attribute. I think it is easier for matlab to serialize the result however as I recall there being a 1-1 correspondence between files & functions.

Comment: @Charles right, but if you change the function definition inside R using the tools `edit()` and `fix()` you still need a way to go from the new function object out to source code (text). IIRC, editing a function in R in the ways suggested by the OP doesn't update the `source` attribute, other than to perhaps loose it??

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the 'source' attribute?

Comment: @user1237875 I wonder if @Charles meant the `srcref` attribute. Do `foo <- function(x) 1:10` and then try `attributes(foo)` and you'll see the `srcref` attribute. IIRC Duncan Murdoch did this work and he had a paper in the R Journal recently describing the functionality etc. I'll leave you to look up the details. However, I doubt this line of investigation will be significantly more useful than just working within an R-aware IDE/text editor.

Comment: Agreed. RStudio has a source-on-save option, so as long as you have all your functions in a file with no top-level R code, the edit/save cycle is just as convenient as fix/save.